What does 深いパーソナリティー mean?
I am not sure about the meaning of 深いパーソナリティー in this question:

キミはその浅村某というやつのことを好きだというが、そもそもキミはそいつ以外の男子の深いパーソナリティーなんて知りやしないだろう？

Understanding 深いパーソナリティー literally as "deep personality" doesn't make sense to me. Maybe I don't understand the use of the word 深い here.

This 深い is an antonym of 表面的な ("superficial"). 深いパーソナリティー is not a set phrase, but it can be understood as referring to a hidden/true  part of someone's personality that is revealed only after getting to know them very well. By the way, "subconscious" is translated into Japanese as 深層意識 (literally "deep conscious").
